# Finding a group of Complex numbers That is Isomorphic to this Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, chemistry

So, I'm reading *Introduction to Symmetry and Group Theory for Chemists* to prepare for a project in Modern Algebra (and out of pure interest) and I've come across a problem that I thought would be pretty simple to solve. Clearly, I'm wrong and it's quite the brain teaser or I'm just not in the right mindset. The following is the problem.

---

Consider the symmetry group of an object for which the only covering operations are the identity and rotations by $120^\circ (=C_3)$ and $240^\circ (=C^2_3$) around the same axis. The multiplication table for this group is:

\begin{array}{c | c c c}
\ & E & C_3 & C_3^2\\
\hline
E & E & C_3 & C_3^2\\
C_3 & C_3 & C_3^2 & E\\
C_3^2 & C_3^2 & E & C_3\\
\end{array}

Can you determine all the possible sets of three complex numbers that satisfy the same multiplication table?

---

So, I've worked in my head a view numbers that could potentially work, but I keep running into a need to have a 4x4 table (i.e the $1,-1,i,-i$ symmetry group). I would imagine that in any case, the identity element should still be $0 + i^0$, but I could be wrong there. At this point, I would just appreciate a hint that might get me on the right track.

Thanks.

Comment: Each of those symmetries satisfy $C_i^3 = 1$. So if you want a complex number like that, you need some $z \in \Bbb C$ so that $z^3 = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You've already (correctly) concluded that $E$ has to be $1$; so really the only question is, "What are the possible values for $C_3$?"

The properties a complex number $z$ must satisfy, in order to be a candidate for $C_3$, are:

- $z\not=1$ (since $C_3\not=E$, and $E$ represents $1$);
- $z^2\not=1$; and
- $z^3=1$.

Now there are two approaches for finding all such $z$:

- Brute force: express $z$ as $a+bi$, $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, and solve $(a+bi)^3=1+0i$. Then check which of the solutions satisfy the other two constraints.
- More cleverly: are you familiar with the *polar representation* of complex numbers, as $re^{i\theta}$? What does multiplication correspond to, for such numbers? This will give you a purely *geometric* solution.

Comment: Thank you! I've never seen the polar representation of complex numbers, but I'm going to try to look at this in both ways. I imagine it will help in the future.

Comment: Check out De Moivre's theorem to get started! And yes, it's super useful.

Comment: A third approach: From your third bullet point, we know that such a $z$ must be a root of $z^3 - 1$.  Factor $z^3 - 1 = (z-1)(z^2 + z + 1)$.  Since $z = 1$ doesn't satisfy the second bullet point, we know that the desired $z$ must be roots of $z^2 +z + 1$, whose roots can be found by the quadratic formula.